# "In your session" or "during your session"

Tags: sentence, sentence-patterns

I have the following sentence but I am confused if it is correct or not.

"I was your student in NTHP Student session"
Or
"I was your student during NTHP Student session"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"During" would be proper in this situation as the session represents a period of time in which you were a student.

"In" would refer to your physical presence at the session; i.e. "I was in the classroom".